# Outlet boundary conditions in lattice Boltzmann method

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, lattice-boltzmann-methods

Here is the flow past a square cylinder configuration. The problem is a viscous and incompressible with parabolic velocity profile using freestream velocity $U$ across a single cylinder. I use the single relaxation time lattice Boltzmann method. For the two-dimensional nine-velocity lattice(D2Q9), the directions of the particles are shown in the picture.

[image]

The parameters: $H=160$, $L=780$, $I=170$, $D=20$, $U_\max=0.0438$,
$\mathrm{density}=1.0$, $dy=dx=1$, $dt=1$, $\mathrm{Re}=160$

The boundary conditions:

- Inlet: He-Zou boundary condition
- Wall: bounce-back conditions
- Outlet: interpolation (Here is the code for outlet BCs)

  ```
  f(1,n,j)=2*f(1,n-1,j)-f(1,n-2,j)
  f(5,n,j)=2*f(5,n-1,j)-f(5,n-2,j)
  f(8,n,j)=2*f(8,n-1,j)-f(8,n-2,j)
  ```

My problem is whether the outlet boundary conditions are right or not. If it is right, why it's about `f1`, `f5`, `f8` rather than `f3`, `f6`, `f7`? In my opinion, it seems that we can't get `f3`, `f6`, `f7` from streaming on the outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Your outlet boundary condition is not correct. In your outlet BCs, you have to impose the value of $f_6$, $f_3$ and $f_7$ since these populations are not updated by the streaming step.

This paper presents a good example on how to do an outflow BC in LBM :
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/40536594_Outflow_boundary_conditions_for_the_lattice_Boltzmann_method

Answer (score 1):

Some other fairly easy methods to assign values to the unknown populations include:

1. You could save the post-collision values of the missing populations $f_3, f_6, f_7$ at timestep $j - 1$ and set them in the $j$'th streaming step as incoming populations.
2. Based on the macroscopic variables $u, \rho$ you can set $f_3, f_6, f_7$ in the streaming step to their equilibrium values.
3. If you know one of $u_x, u_y, \rho$ at the outlet, you can also use the Zou-He boundary conditions you already used at the inlet.